# how to power M910 without chassis

Tags: dell-poweredge

How to power M910 PowerEdge, without using the recommended M1000e chassis?

I have an M910 blade server board, ram, and CPUs, but I do not know what power cables/supplies should use to power it up. Dell recommended, and maybe required, to use M1000e chassis; in fact, I just need one blade server board, thus, having a chassis is quite unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

Blades can be cheaper than complete servers because they aren’t complete servers. You’ll need all kinds of I/O that the chassis provides; not just power.

TL;DR: Get a regular server unless your use case benefits from a blade solution.